# Problem when deploying a node js application using github api

Tags: node.js, api, github, deployment

Im actually develop an backend application who takes an array of repos of github and check if they exists. (
(is to check my students' exams.) If they exists, how many commits have and their branches.
This is the repo: https://github.com/veronicajujuy/check-intro-back
In my local machine it runs, i'm calling the api like this:

```
const urlRepo = `https://api.github.com/repos/${repo.usuario}/${repo.nombreRepo}`;
 try {
      const respuestaRepo = await axios.get(urlRepo, {
      headers: {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`
      }});
console.log(`El repositorio ${repo.nombreRepo} existe.`);
existe = true;
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(`El repositorio ${repo.nombreRepo} no existe.`);
 }
```

I put this information in an object and the app gives me back the information I need:

```
{
    usuario: 'josepp',
    repo: 'Examen1',
    existe: true,
    commits: 1,
    branches: [ 'master' ]
  },
```

but when im deploy in render.com and in railway.app every single repo shows to be false...
https://check-intro-back-production.up.railway.app/existenRepos
What could be the problem?

I'm deploy, first in render.com, then railway, but it remains the same problem...